# Using Field Calculator vb to check for name with /n in the string?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3, vbscript

I am calculating values for a field (Score) based upon the names from another field (Modified). One name is "`blaugh\nblaugh`". Field Calculator keeps treating the name as having a new line command.

I have tried using Like, Right and Contains but the Field calculator does not seem to be able to use those commands. I am stumped.

**Ex1**

```vbs
elseif  [Modified] ="blaugh\nblaugh" then
Score =7
```

**Ex2**

```vbs
elseif Right( [Modified], -6) = "blaugh" then
Score =7
```

**Ex3**

```vbs
elseif [Modified] LIKE "*nblagh" then
Score =7
```

I am using vb in ModelBuilder and ArcCatalog 10.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems has been solved thanks to a user on GeoNet.

**Solution**

```vbs
elseif InStr( [Modified], nblaugh) then Score =7
```

Answer (score 0):

For an exact match, I believe this should also work in VB:

```vbs
elseif [Modified] ="blaugh" & Chr(10) & "blaugh" then Score =7
```